# Finding the latest version of package which doesn't require upgrading libc (on Debian)

Tags: apt, aptitude

When I try to upgrade packages using `aptitude -t wheezy-backports`, they often require newer `libc` than is installed. Proposed solutions remove hundreds of packages. Is there a way to request only the versions which wouldn't require upgrading `libc` (preferably from the command line)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you get the same result executing the following command?

```
apt-get dist-upgrade -t wheezy-backports
```

Are you running a pure wheezy+wheezy-backports environment? I currently use wheezy-backports but I have never been asked to upgrade libc. In fact there are no backports of libc6 in wheezy-backports ([link](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)).

Answer (score 1):

You can mark libc6 as **hold** and it will upgrade only the packages which doesn't need to upgrade libc6.

```
apt-mark hold libc6
apt update && apt upgrade -uV
```

You should know **the backports repository it's not a full distro version**. It only contains some packages which are newer than the standard distro version. In your case the wheezy-backports has some newer packages for the wheezy version, which should run on wheezy without so many changes and without upgrading all the packages to the next version.

You can remove the hold mark with `apt-mark unhold libc6`

The apt dist-upgrade bypasses those holds, so use apt upgrade instead.